# EditText validation runs only once

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have the following validation

```
private boolean validatePin() {

    String pin = pinTxt.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pin) || pin.length() != 4) {
        pin_layout.setError(mContext.getString(R.string.err_msg_pin));
        requestFocus(pinTxt);
        return false;
    } else {
        pin_layout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And I'm calling it on afterTextChanged like this:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.pinTxt:
                validatePin();
                break;
        }
    }
```

What I get with this is that the error text shows the first time I start typing less than 4 chars in the editText, but when I delete everything and start typing again I get no error message. Any ideas how to show this error message every time I start typing in the editText and not only the first time?

Comment: setErrorEnabled(true)?

Comment: what is your `pin_layout`? can you please explain that?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I set it to true in the if - didn't work. Then I tried to set it in else but it showed the error message every time I type something (like it should if its constantly true).

Comment: used the && operator Instead of || operator or String pin=""; than take pin=pinTxt.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: @himanshu1496 pin_layout is a TextInputLayout which wraps an {@link android.widget.EditText} (or descendant) to show a floating label when the hint is hidden due to the user inputting text.

Comment: please check my answer it should work.

Comment: I have changed `pinTxt.setError()` to `pin_layout.setError()` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
pinTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        validatePin();
    }
});
```

And

```
private boolean validatePin() {

String pin = pinTxt.getText().toString().trim();

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pin) || pin.length() != 4) {
    pin_layout.setError(mContext.getString(R.string.err_msg_pin));
    requestFocus(pinTxt);
    return false;
} else {
    pin_layout.setError(null);
}
return true;
}
```

So here I am setting error to the `textInputLayout` which is taking the input for pin and setting error `null` when the error condition is not fulfilled which will hide the error.

Comment: Cool! happy coding!! :D

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your edit text view in xml

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but setting that property in the xml didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
 pinTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            validatePin();
        }
    });
```

try this, addTextChange listener to EditText. Now put your validation code in AfterTextChanged function of TextWatcher

Comment: why do you think that his afterTextChanged does not work? (it does work btw)

Comment: yes it work. but when you add textChangeListener to EdtiText then there is no need to check it  "switch (view.getId())"  like that. so i simplified its code for use

Comment: Simple is subjective. Suggesting to refactor code while not changing anything that really matters is not really useful

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing it your way, but it still didn't show error after deleting the first input.